# Fix XSS issue for windows.location.hostname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, xss

Currently, I am re-routing to an external URL using the following code:

```
<Route exact path={`${rootUrl}/www/test`} component={() => { window.location = `https://${window.location.hostname}/www/someURL?fixing=true`; return null; }} />
```

But the above line is causing XSS vulnerabilities on testing. How do I fix this issue ? Should I encode it ?

Comment: Why do you think this is vulnerable to XSS? It might be vulnerable to open redirection, but exploitability would still depend on external factors, and I don't think this is vulnerable to XSS. Does this come from some SAST tool?

Comment: Came as cross-site scripting issue in FOD scan test.

Comment: I think this is a definite false positive for XSS, and if the server is configured correctly, it is also a false positive for open redirection. (I mean, open redirect was not even mentioned, so it's not technically a false positive per se :) but that would be a logical thought and a potential vulnerability in the code above due to redirecting to a domain from user input).